# System logs shows uninstalled program still working (ExpressVPN)

Tags: dpkg, uninstall, vpn, syslog

So I had ExpressVPN, a commercial VPN service. I uninstalled it a long time ago (restarted many times since then), but I just saw this in syslog:

> Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 177.
>   Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[1]: Stopped ExpressVPN Daemon.
>   Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[1]: Started ExpressVPN Daemon.
>   Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[3871]: expressvpn.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
>   Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[3871]: expressvpn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/expressvpnd: No such file or directory
>   Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
>   Mar  8 13:03:39 elliott systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Mar  8 13:03:44 elliott systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

And it keeps repeating (incrementing the counter).

I checked that it's not installed with dpkg:

> elliott@elliott:~$ sudo dpkg -r expressvpn
>   [sudo] password for elliott:
>   dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove expressvpn which isn't installed

I can't provide the exact steps of bash commands that I originally used to install the program, as I did it 2 years ago (no longer in bash history). I followed the bash install steps from their official website. (If it's helpful, I could provide a list of what I think my steps likely were.)

`grep -rni "expressvpn" /` gave huge outputs, mostly caches, but also a lot that would require a lot of work for me to figure out what it's doing, like:

> /home/elliott/.local/share/app-info/xmls/extensions-web.xml:8550: `<id>expressvpn_manager_faidoc</id>`

A lot of these could be code that legitimately remains after the uninstall, like package managers.

Questions (FYI, I'm a programmer, but know little about networking/administration):

1. Can I deduce from the logs that there is some expressvpn process
   running, or is it possible that it's a non-expressvpn process that's
   trying to call/pipe to expressvpn and failing?
2. How could I find where the expressvpn process is being called?

Comment: Please click [edit] to let us know these facts. 1) What's the command you used to uninstall it? 2) Which OS is installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.), and which release number? 3) Have you rebooted since you performed the uninstall? If not, please do that, then recheck for the VPN to see if it still runs. Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Comment: Try `sudo service expressvpn stop` then `sudo service expressvpn disable`.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks. I tired it, but at the disable I get "expressvpn: unrecognized service"

Comment: Try `whereis expressvpn`.

Comment: Strangely I just get "expressvpn:"

Comment: And also `ps auxc | grep -i express`

Comment: Let me do the first two commands a little differently... just in case there are caps in the name... `ls /etc/init | grep -i express` and `ls /etc/init.d | grep -i express`, and `ls -R /etc/systemd | grep -i express`,

Comment: Thanks. It appears twice in systemd. I'll check that out now. Both "ls" gave "No such file or directory", and the "ps auxc" grep outputted nothing.

Comment: Give me the exact names that were found in /etc/systemd. They're probably in /etc/systemd/system.

Comment: @heynnema, You're right: /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service, and /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/expressvpn.service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105322/discussion-between-elliott-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments...

ExpressVPN didn't fully uninstall. To manually remove the remaining parts...

`sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service`

`sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/expressvpn.service`

`reboot`

Comment: Worked for me in Fedora 32.